# scaling divs and images css/javascript depending on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div which has inside few divs, few images and two selects. I want to make my main division and all of its content to automatically resize depending on the screen. How can I do it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You're more likely to get useful feedback if you include some code that shows what you've already tried (even better if it's in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)!).

Comment: you should look into Responsive Design. I have done similar things with CSS Media Queries. It has been about a year, and I don't have any examples with me, that was at my last job.

Answer (score 2):

You use media queries for this. It is called responsive design

```
@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  div {
    width: 40px;
  }
}
```

This will essentially change the width of `div` to `40px` **only if** the screen width is less than 699px

Further reference:
[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tried-and-tested script which even accomodates prehistoric browsers such as IE4. It takes the viewport approach, which means divisions can be updated when a user resizes their browser window.

```
<script>

    window.onResize = function() {

  if (window.innerWidth) { // All browsers but IE
    myViewportWidth  =  window.innerWidth; 
    myViewportHeight =  window.innerHeight;
  }
  else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
    // These functions are for IE6 when there is a DOCTYPE
    myViewportWidth  = document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
    myViewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }
  else if (document.body.clientWidth) {
    // These are for IE4, IE5, and IE6 without a DOCTYPE
    myViewportWidth  = document.body.clientWidth;
    myViewportHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }

      // now call customResize with your chosen new dimensions
      // you'll probably need to insert a bit of arithmetic here:
      //   *calculate new values here*
      customResize( MY_NEW_X_VALUE, MY_NEW_Y_VALUE );          

   }// function 
</script>
```

Once you have the viewport dimensions you can resize your main division according to the specific dimensions of the viewport. 
I generally use one main division for the content placed inside the 'body' element for convenience. Then modify the following script according to the dimensions you need.

```
<script>

     function customResize(newWidth, newHeight){
            var X = newWidth;
            var Y = newHeight;
            var e = document.getElementById('mainDiv').style.width  = 'X';
            var f = document.getElementById('mainDiv').style.height = 'Y';
</script>
```

Take care to test the code with different browsers however - sometimes odd versions of browsers can return unusual values.